# Extjs gridfilters

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I have an issue with gridfilters plugin

« Filters » option is visible but the sub-menu for Filters option is not visible
I have this warning in console
"Using showBy on a non-floating component"

The grid definition is :

```
                xtype: 'grid',
                store: store,
                iconCls: 'icon-grid',
                frame: true,
                width: 700,
                height: 500,

                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                    store: store,   // mismo que el store GridPanel
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    displayInfo: true
                }],
                plugins:     ['gridfilters'],
                columns: [
                            {header: 'Company',dataIndex: 'company',  flex: 1,
                                filter: 
                                {
                                    type: 'string',
                                    itemDefaults: {
                                        emptyText: 'Search for...'
                                    }
                                },
                                 editor: {
                                     xtype: 'textfield'
                                 }

                            },
                            {header: 'Price',dataIndex: 'price',  flex: 1,
                                filter: 'number'
                            },
                            {header: 'Change',dataIndex: 'change',  flex: 1},
                            {header: 'Last change',dataIndex: 'lastChange',xtype: 'datecolumn', format:'d/m/Y',  flex: 1}


                        ]
```

Can you help me about this point?

Comment: The code you posted looks correct at the first glance. The problem must be elsewhere. Can you create a demo of the problem at https://fiddle.sencha.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the features property instead of the plugins one, as follows:

```
features: {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: true,
    local: false
}
```